# Is there a easy way to add key values from map to tuple2(String, String) and return

Tags: scala, tuples

I am trying to use `play.api.libs.ws.StandaloneWSRequest.addHttpHeaders(hdrs: (String, String)*)`. Instead of adding comma separated values, I am trying to write a custom function which will return a mutable.Map with keys and values based on an if condition. But I am getting the error below:

> ```
> type mismatch;
>  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]
>  required: (String, String)
>         .withHttpHeaders(Map(map, `if condition parameter`))
> ```

I am trying to write a custom function which return `k:v` pairs based on if condition. I recently started learning scala

Comment: You can `fold` over the `Map` and accumulate the values on whatever condition you want. [Documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B). Or you can use [filter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#filter(f:A=%3EBoolean):Iterator[A])

Comment: You can do `.withHttpHeaders(map.(...).toSeq : _*)` but, TBH. I would probably disapprove code like that in a code review.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried to use below code snippet, But I still see the error Required Tuple2[String, String].  `def flattenMap(map: Map[String, String], str: String): Seq[(String, String)] = {
    val states = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
    map.keys.foreach{ key =>
      if(key.contains(str)){
        println("key "+key.split(":")(1))
        println("value "+map(key))
        states.put(key.split(":")(1),map(key))
      }
    }
    return states.toSeq:_*
  }`  And Can explain why this would be a bad code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez All I want to do is write a custom method to return headers which can be reused for other Http calls

Comment: @Raj right your method would return an immutable `Seq[(String, String)]`, internally that method may use a `Map` maybe a mutable one if that is easier. Then when you need the headers you do this: `withHttpHeaders(createHeaders(...) : _*)` where `createHeaders` is the custom method you created.